# Get tag's children count with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm writing an analyzing tool that counts how many children has any HTML tag in the source code.

I mapped the code with BeautifulSoup, and now I want to iterate over any tag in the page and count how many children it has.

What will be the best way to iterate over all the tags? How can I for example get all the tags that do not have any children?

Comment: Can you give us an example of your HTML source code and what you have tried already?

Comment: Suggestion: Find all tags that have no children ('leaves') then work your way back up.

Comment: Can I any compare tags between two soups?

Answer (score 4):

If you use `find_all()` with no arguments you can iterate over every tag.

You can get how many children a tag has by using [`len(tag.contents)`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children).

To get a list of all tags with no children:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('someHTMLFile.html', 'r'), 'html.parser')
body = soup.body

empty_tags = []

for tag in body.find_all():
   if len(tag.contents) == 0:
      empty_tags.append(tag)

print empty_tags
```

or...

```
empty_tags = [tag for tag in soup.body.find_all() if len(tag.contents) == 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can count the tag's children by using the `len()` function.

```
meta_tags = soup.findAll('meta' , property="article:tag")
if len(meta_tags) < 1:
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I use BeautifulSoup for the same. Using the **findChildren** method of each element

In the below code, **fullData** contains the HTML string of the webpage

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(fullData)
elements = soup.findAll()

def findElements(dataList,el):
    temp=el.findChildren()
    if(len(temp)==0):
        print(el.get_text())

tempResults=[findElements(dataList,el) for el in elements]
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel... especially not in ways that don't roll. BeautifulSoup does
count the children for you, unsurprisingly.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
doc = BS('<html><head><title>Example</title></head><body><h1>The Truth</h1>'
         + '<p>It is out there, Neo.</p></body></html>')
print(len(doc.html))
# 2, head and body
print(len(list(x for x in doc.html.find_all())))
# 5, because find_all() finds... all?
print(len(list(x for x in doc.html.children)))
# 2, but instead of letting BeautifulSoup count it as it deems best, 
# you actually gather the pieces and count them yourself
print(len(doc.html.contents))
# 2, functionally the same as the prior, just more readable
```